# Why can't you create a 1 statement function without curly braces?

Tags: java, c#, c++

So, in most programming language, if you are using a loop or an if, you can do it without curly braces if there is only a single statement in it, example:

```
if (true)
    //Single statement;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    //Single Statement

while (true)
    //Single statement
```

However, it doesn't work for functions, example:

```
void myFunction()
    //Single Statement
```

So, my question, why doesn't it work for functions?

Comment: Which language exactly? Or it is general OOP?

Comment: @SonerGönül It's the same in all languages

Comment: Syntactic grammar & compiler... A bunch of magic :)

Comment: Well not a single statement. Try to write only one statement in method

Comment: "because that is the way the language designers chose to write the spec"; quite possibly because it is insanely easy to make a complicated mess of things otherwise...

Comment: There's no interesting reason. It's just how the languages are specified.

Comment: Mayn't be of much use. If it is a non void return function one liner would be of not much use. That would be extra overhead for the compiler to check, which might lead to longer compile times.

Comment: This is just how they made the compilers. Nothing special.

Comment: C#6 will allow it - "expression bodied function members".  e.g., public Point Move(int dx, int dy) => new Point(x + dx, y + dy);  Not that this is an improvement...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C++ needs it to disambiguate some constructs:

```
void Foo::bar() const int i = 5;
```

Now does the `const` belong to `bar` or `i` ?

Answer (score 5):

Because language grammar forbids you to do that.

The Java grammar defines a method as following:

```
MethodDeclaration:
    MethodHeader MethodBody
```

Methodbody as:

```
MethodBody:
    Block 
    ;
```

Which means either a Block (see below) or a single semicolon

```
Block:
    { BlockStatementsopt }
```

And a block as one or more statements within curly brackets.

However an if is defined as:

```
IfThenStatement:
    if ( Expression ) Statement
```

Where no block is needed after the closing ) and therefore a single line is ok.

Why they chose to define it that way? One can only guess.

Grammar can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html

Answer (score 5):

This is not a rule, in some languages you can (Python? Yes, I know that's really contrived example :)) ), in other you cannot.

You could very well extend your question for example to class and namespaces, for example, why not:

```
namespace Example
    class Foo : public Bar
        public: std::string myMethod()
            return "Oh noes!";
```

right? At each level, that's just a single item, so why not skip the braces everywhere?

The answer is at the same time simple and complex.

In simple terms, it's about readability. Remember that you can layout your code as you like, **since whitespaces are usually discarded** by the compiler:

```
namespace Example class Foo : public Bar public: std::string myMethod() return "Oh noes!";
```

Well, that starts looking unreadable. Notice that if you add the braces back

```
namespace Example { class Foo : public Bar { public: std::string myMethod() {return "Oh noes!";}}}
```

then it, strangely, becomes somewhat comprehensible.

The actual problem is not readability (who cares anyways? I'm joking of course) but in the latter: comprehension. Not only you must be able to comprehend the code - the compiler must. And for the compiler there is no such thing as "oh, this looks like function". The compiler **must be absolutely sure** that it is a function. Also, it must be completely sure about where it starts, where it ends, and so on. And it must do that without looking at whitespaces too much, since C-family languages allow you to do add them in any quantities you like.

So, let's look again at the packed-up no-braces example

```
namespace Example class Foo : public Bar public : std::string myMethod() return "Oh noes!";
                            ^                   ^    ^^
```

I've marked some problematic symbols. Assuming you could define a grammar that handles it, please note how the meaning of ":" character changes. At one time it's denoting that you're specifying inheritance, at other point it's specifying access modifier to a method, at third place it's just namespace qualifier. Ok, the third one could be discarded if you were smart and noticed it's actually '::' symbol, not just a ':' character.

Also, meaning of keywords can change:

```
namespace Example class Foo : public Bar public : std::string myMethod() return "Oh noes!";
                              ^^^^^^     ^^^^^^
```

At first place, it defines access modifier for inherited base class, at second place it defined access modifier for a method. What's more, at first place it's **not meant** to be followed by a ":" and at second place it's required to be followed by it!

So many rules, exceptions and corner cases, and we covered just 2 simple things: public and ':'. Now, imagine you are to specify the grammar for the whole language. You describe everything in the way you'd like to have. But, when you gather all the rules together, they at some point may start overlap and collide with each other. After adding Nth rule, it may happen that your 'compiler' would be unable to tell whether the 'public' actually marks inheritance, or starts a method:

```
namespace Example class Foo : public ::Bar public : std::string myMethod() return "Oh noes!";
                              ^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^
```

Note that I only changed the `Bar` to `::Bar`. I only added a namespace qualifier, and now our rule of "public is followed by a colon" is trashed. As I now added a rule that "base class names may have namespace qualifiers", I also must add more rules to cover yet another corner cases - to remove the ambiguity of the meaning of "public" and ":" in this place.

To cut the long talk: the more rules, the more problem you have. The "compiler" grows, gets slower, eats more resources to work. This results in inability to handle large code files, or in frustration when the user must wait oh-so-long for that module to compile.

But what's worse for the user is, the more complex or ambiguous, the **worse error messages are**. Noone wants to use a compiler that is unable to parse some code and also unable to tell you what's wrong with it.

Remember in C++ what happens when you forget some ';' in a `.h` file? Or when you forget some `}`? Compiler reports you an error 30 or 300 lines farther. This is because the ';' and '{}' can be ommitted in many places, and for that 30 or 300 lines, the compiler simply does not yet know that's something wrong! Were the braces required everywhere, the point of error could be pinpointed faster.

The other way: making them optional at namespace, class, or function level, would remove the basic block-starts/block-ends markers and, at least:

- could make the grammar ambiguous (and hence force to add more rules)
- could hurt detecting (and reporting!) errors

any part of which noone really wants.

The C++ grammar is so complex, that it actually might be not possible to omit the braces at those places at all. For Java or plain C, I think it could be possible to make a grammar/compiler that would not require them, but would it would still hurt error reporting much. Especially in C which allows to use `#include` and macros. In early Java, the impact might be lesser, as the grammar is relatively simple, compared i.e. to current C++..

Probably the simplest, fastest, easiest to implement, and probably easiest to learn grammar would .. require braces (or any other delimiters) just about everywhere. Check LISP for example. But then, large part of your work would consist of constantly writing the same required markers, which many language-users simply does not like (i.e. I get nauseous when I need to work on some old code in VisualBasic with its "if then end if" yuck)

Now, if you look at brace-less language like Python - how does they solve it? They denote the block-starts/block-ends by .. intendation. In this language **you must** indent your code properly. If you don't indent it correctly, it will not compile at all, or it the loops/functions/etc will silently get their code messed up, because the compiler will not know what part does belong to which scope. No free lunch here again.

Answer (score 1):

Basically a method(function) is a collection of statements that are grouped together to perform an operation. We group the statements for reusable. That is if you know that a set of instructions will used often in that case we create it as a separate function.

If you can perform the task in a single line of code, then why do you need to write a function?

Comment: For the same reason you can write `if (true)` and it still compiles. (I don't think this question is about the practicality of single-statement functions, but rather their syntax in the language.)

Comment: Also, nearly every getter and setter in Java is a single-statement function. Something to keep in mind...

Answer (score 1):

Because the grammar of the language doesn't allow you to.

Here is the grammar for a function in C taken from the ISO/IEC 9899-1999 specification:

```
6.9.1 Function definitions
Syntax
1     function-definition:
          declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-listopt compound-statement
```

The compound-statement part is the body of a function, and a compound statement is declared as

```
compound-statement:
    { block-item-listopt }
```

i.e. it starts and ends with braces.

An `if`, `while` or similar body can have a `statement` as its body.

```
 (6.8.5) iteration-statement:
             while ( expression ) statement
```

A statement can be one of several constructs.

```
statement:
    labeled-statement
    compound-statement
    expression-statement
    selection-statement
    iteration-statement
    jump-statement
```

of which only `compound-statement` requires the braces.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ you need a compound statement to make a function body - which is actually surrounded with curly barces. It does not mean you need to have curly braces right immediately, following will compile just fine:

```
int foobar()
    try {
      return 1;
    }
    catch (...){return 0;}
```

Comment: This conflates *function-try-block* and normal *try-block*. The latter is a statement (but not a compound statement). The former is not a statement at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can't precisely say there are no one statement functions in C#. Anonymous methods could be one of them. Without single line statements we could not have Lambda expression in c#. The C# 3.0 wouldn't be exist.

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to add that extra parsing code in the compiler because the functionality is really useless, how many one line methods have you written that are not accessors or mutators?  This has been dealt with in C# via properties but not yet in Java.

So the reason is, it's unlikely to be used considering most developers discourage leaving out optional bracket blocks anyway.

Comment: I'd say accessors and mutators are a big part of Java...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when pointing out the answer's age.